# How To find Out Higher Values To Low Values with php

Tags: php

i have some data in my notepad and i want to find out maximum values to minimum values with php My data Looks like This

```
a:849444988- b:10.0 
a:748449844- b:15.0 
a:940849847- b:20.0 
a:474844994- b:55.0
```

and so on..
now how to arrange it with higher to lower 
i want output that show uid 474844994 have 55 bal

Comment: Why does this have a php tag?  Shouldn't this have a notepad tag? If you are trying to sort these strings with php, where is your coding attempt?

Comment: actually i am not understanding how to implant in php and what code i need to be use

Comment: Do you know how to accept an answer on StackOverflow?  Please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

First declare your file data as an array of lines using `file()`.

Then perform a custom sort which leverages natural sorting on the numeric substring that trails `b:`.

From here, you can continue processing the data as an array, or implode it back into its original string form ...whatever your task requires.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ah9jA))

```
//$lines=file('your.txt');
$lines=[
    'a:849444988- b:10.0',
    'a:748449844- b:15.0',
    'a:123456789- b:120.0', 
    'a:940849847- b:20.0', 
    'a:474844994- b:55.0'
];

usort($lines,function($a,$b){
    return strnatcmp( substr($b,strpos($b,'b:')+2) , substr($a,strpos($a,'b:')+2) );
    // $b is listed before $a in strnatcmp() to achieve DESC order
});

echo implode("\n",$lines);
```

Output:

```
a:123456789- b:120.0
a:474844994- b:55.0
a:940849847- b:20.0
a:748449844- b:15.0
a:849444988- b:10.0
```

Comment: @Game if this answer doesn't work for you, please show me the output from `var_export(file('your.txt'))`

Answer (score -1):

First, you read your file into an array using `file()` this will create one array element per line. Then use `arsort()` to sort from high to low.

```
$arr = arsort(file('filepath.txt'));
print_r($arr);//output array
```

Comment: Wrong.  For a few reasons.  Please delete this thought bubble.

Comment: @mickmackusa I won't delete anything. Please provide valuable feedback if you say this is wrong.

Comment: You did not test your code.  I doubt you read the question carefully.  I am not here to babysit other people's posts. This answer clearly will never deliver the expected result.  When new users see a user with thousands of rep points, they assume that person is delivering "the goods".  You are doing yourself and Stackoverflow no favors by leaving this on the site.